# Can an instance in GCE have two virtual ethernet interfaces? How can I get a second interface (i.e., eth1) two bind to a second custom subnet?

Tags: google-compute-engine

How can I add a second virtual interface to a Google Compute Engine instance, and configure second virtual interface to use a separate custom subnet?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a static target internal IP address using routes where you can set up the instance and network to receive packets sent to the IP which requires creating a virtual interface to your instance. You can have more information in this Help Center [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#staticnetworkaddress)